# Scriptlet variable in div id

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

Hi Can we assign scriptlet variable value to div id in jsp?
Im trying like this in my jsp:

```
 <%int nc=1; %> 
  <div id="nc"+<%=nc%> class="n_content active">
       Some div content
        <%nc++;%>
 </div>
 <div id="nc"+<%=nc%> class="n_content" style="opacity: 1;">             
                                               Some div content
        <%nc++;%>
 </div>
```

The output i wanted is

```
  <div id="nc1" class="n_content active">
       Some div content
        <%nc++;%>
 </div>
 <div id="nc2" class="n_content" style="opacity: 1;">             
                                               Some div content
        <%nc++;%>
 </div>
```

But Im unable to get this.. Can someone tell me where Im going wrong?

Comment: Madhavi,Avoid using scriplets in the code.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<div id="nc<%=nc%>" class="n_content active">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code.

```
 <%int nc=1; %> 

 <div id="nc<%=nc%>" class="n_content active">
         <!--Some div content-->
        <%nc++;%>
 </div>
 <div id="nc<%=nc%>" class="n_content" style="opacity: 1;">             
         <!--Some div content-->
        <%nc++;%>
 </div>
```