# Can anyone answer why this does not work with struts?

Tags: jsp, for-loop, struts2, scriptlet

[Scriptlet variable in div id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804202/scriptlet-variable-in-div-id)

I have the same question as in the above link but with Struts2, when I put the code within 
 as below it does not work.

```
 <s:form>

        <%!int i, j;%>
        <%
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        %>
        <%
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        %>
        <div class="One" id="j<%=j%>">
            Hey<%=i%></div>
        <%
            }
        %>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </s:form>
```

I know this is not good to use scriptlet, but atleast it should work.

Comment: what do you mean by `does not work` ? What html output do you get for the above code ?

Comment: I want id to be the value of "i".
But in html it shows id="j<%=j%>" i.e. the jsp code is not evaluated.
But it is evaluated when I don't use struts tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Avoid scriptlets
2. Your code will generate multiple element with the same ID, that is not allowed.

Solution:

1. Use [Struts Iterator](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/iterator.html)
2. Place both variables in ID.

```
<s:form>
    <s:iterator begin="0" end="5" status="i" >
        <s:iterator begin="0" end="5" status="j" >
            <div id="<s:property value="%{'i' + #i.index + 'j' + #j.index}"> ">
                Hey <s:property value="%{#i.index}"/> 
            </div>
        </s:iterator>
    </s:iterator>
</s:form>
```

Note that

> The begin, end and step attributes are only available from 2.1.7 on

Comment: Thank you but i was asking why that do not work.
Please tell if you know. 
Thank you.